# Why does smo backup work when given direct path but not through save file dialog

Tags: c#, smo, savefiledialog

Hi There I'm trying to set up a program that opens a save file dialog and then uses that save location to take a backup of a remote sql server using smo. It works when I give it the network location directly.

```
 if (checkBox7.Checked)
        {

                // Displays a SaveFileDialog so the user can save the Backup
                // assigned to Button2.
                try
                {
                    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
                    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save SQL Backup";
                    saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false;
                    saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
                    saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "bak";
                    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "SQL Backup (*.bak)|*.bak";
                    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
                    saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "\\\\" + Server_Name;
                    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = false;

                    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        SaveFileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                    }
                    saveFileDialog1.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception exsavefile)
                {
                    stfrm.txtMessages.AppendText(String.Format("An Error has occured in the save dialog process \n\nMessage: {0}", exsavefile.Message) + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            try
            {
                //FileNameBackup = "\\\\bmslondon01\\SQL Backups\\Test\\test folder\\test.bak";
                stfrm.txtMessages.AppendText(String.Format("File Location Chosen: {0}", FileNameBackup) + Environment.NewLine);

                Backup bkp = new Backup();
                bkp.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                bkp.Database = SelectDatabase_Name;
                bkp.Devices.AddDevice(FileNameBackup, DeviceType.File);
                stfrm.pbCurrent.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
                stfrm.pbCurrent.Value = 0;
                stfrm.pbCurrent.Maximum = 100;
                stfrm.pbCurrent.Value = 10;

                bkp.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
                bkp.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(ProgressEventHandler);

                connbackup = new ServerConnection();
                connbackup.ServerInstance = Server_Name;

                srv = new Server(connbackup);
                bkp.SqlBackup(srv);

                stfrm.txtMessages.AppendText(String.Format("Database Backup to {0}", SaveFileName) + Environment.NewLine);
                stfrm.pbOverall.Value = 15;
                stfrm.pbCurrent.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            }
            catch (Exception exBackup)
            {
                stfrm.txtMessages.AppendText(String.Format("An Error has occured -  Sql Error Message: {0} \n\n  - File failed: {1}", exBackup.Message, SaveFileName) + Environment.NewLine);
                stfrm.txtMessages.ScrollToCaret();
                stfrm.pbOverall.Value = 15;
            }
```

As you can see there is a commented out like where I set the FileNameBackup directly and it works however when I set it thought the save file dialog it doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Use the debugger to find out the value of `FileNameBackup` in `AddDevice(FileNameBackup, DeviceType.File)` at runtime. It might not be what you expect...

Comment: It wasn't what I expected until I changed it to .ToString() and then it worked. That's all I changed.

Comment: Remove the ToString and observe that it still works. For some reason. (I don't know the reason.)

Comment: Point taken, I have no idea what is causing the issue then, as I didn't change anything else....